# Some questions about regression model

Tags: regression, self-study, econometrics

I'm a student who just started to learn econometrics. Recently, I have some trouble with the regression model. The specific question is as follows:

> Suppose that a researcher uses data from a certain country in the past 30 years to study the relationship between economic growth$(Y)$ and consumption$(X_1)$, investment$(X_2)$, and exports$(X_3)$
> \begin{equation}
> Y=\alpha_0+\alpha_1X_1+\alpha_2X_2+\alpha_3X_3+\epsilon
> \end{equation}
> Through several calculations, some results are as follows: the variance of $Y$ is 5%, and the adjusted R-square of the regression model is 0.6.
>
> Q1:Give an unbiased estimate of the random disturbance term
>
> Q2:Assuming that the variance of $X_2$ is 0.08, the correlation coefficient between $X_1$ and $X_2$ is 0.5, $X_2$ and $X_3$ are not correlated, and the estimate of $\alpha_2$ is 0.35, please use the variance of $\hat{\epsilon}$ in Q1 to estimate the variance of $\hat{\alpha_2}$
>
> Q3:If the model is not $Y=\alpha_0+\alpha_1X_1+\alpha_2X_2+\alpha_3X_3+\epsilon$, but $Y=\beta_0+\beta_1X_1+\beta_2X_2+\eta$, under what circumstances $\alpha_1=\beta_1$?

Here is my thought:

For Question 1, We have Adjusted R-Square $\bar{R^2}=1-\frac{SSE/(n-k-1)}{SST/(n-1)}$, $\hat{\sigma}^2=\frac{SSE}{n-k-1}$, and $S_Y^2=\frac{1}{n-1}SST$. That is, $\hat{\sigma^2}=S_Y^2(1-\bar{R}^2)=0.05\cdot(1-0.6)=0.02$

For Question 2, I have no idea about it. Actually, I don’t know how to use the conditions given in the title.

For the last one, my idea is to test the coefficient of $X_3$ of the original model by using a t-test. If we can't reject the null hypothesis, then it should be the latter model, which means $\alpha_1$ is equal to $\alpha_2$.

I would be very grateful if someone helps me to solve this question.

Comment: Consider adding the [tag:self-study] tag. See [how it works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).